# Changing a TextView on an Android Widget from within the onReceive method rather than onUpdate

Tags: android, android-widget, android-service, android-broadcast

I'm developing an application that runs a service which regularly sends broadcasts about its current state. Those broadcasts are received by my `AppWidgetProvider` using its `onReceive` method:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_STATUS_CHANGED)) {
        Bundle b = intent.getBundleExtra("updateInfo");
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_app_control);
        // Doesn't work for some reason
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.informationTextView, b.getString(MyService.BIT_OF_INFORMATION));

        // Update widgets
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, AppControlWidgetProvider.class));
        this.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }
}
```

However, even though I've added the call to `onUpdate`, the new text that was meant to be set using `setTextViewText` does not make it to the actual widgets. If I make the bundle that I've taken the information from available to the whole instance of the class (saving it in an attribute, for the sake of testing) and make the exact same call to `setTextViewText` from within the `onUpdate` method, the `TextView` updates as expected.

I've browsed SO regarding this topic to some extent by now, but everywhere else setting the `TextView` text from within the `onReceive` method in the exact same manner I'm doing it (unless I'm missing something, that is) seems to work perfectly fine.

Comment: dear koala , please edit to add .. code snippet that you are using to send update.

Comment: Hello relsell, are you referring to the code that sends the broadcast? Or do you actually mean the part which sends the update to the widget? The latter, in a manner of speaking, happens within the last three lines of actual code (after `// Update widgets`).

In case you are referring to the former, I'd like to point out again that the broadcast indeed makes it to the `AppWidgetProvider`.